# Проблема с ComboBox в WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Проблема в том, что ComboBox не отображает возвращаемый элемент
Начнём сначала. У меня есть

1. ComboBox
2. Свойство CurrentDriverForMachine, куда записывается выбранный элемент (естественно, и возвращается оттуда)
3. ListBox
4. Свойство, которое возвращает выбранный элемент в ListBox-е 
   Идея в чем. У меня есть ListBox. Я выбираю там элемент, и у меня (на другой половине экрана) появляется окно редактирования. В этом окне редактирования отображается информация выбранного элемента. Также в этом окне содержится ComboBox, в котором можно выбрать "Чтото этаковое".

Это свойство, к которому привязан ComboBox (Выбранный элемент)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора элемента в ListBox-е (В другом месте вызываю OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDriverForMachine")) это свойство возвращает объект. Проблема в том, что если этот объект был установлен ранее (то есть программа закрылась, открылась опять) ничего в выбранный элемент не устанавливается (хотя, значение возвращается)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
XAML код ComboBox-a
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот тут должно быть значение (свойство его возвращает). Если его утсановить сейчас, то пока программу не закроешь - установленное значение будет показываться правильно, и не будет сбиваться. Но, как только закроешь и откроешь - ничего нет (опять же, свойство все что нужно возвращает)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал SelectedItem - там вообще полный аттаз...

Comment: Можете минимальный самодостаточный пример сделать? Пока вообще не понимаю что у вас происходит...

Comment: Несколько минут. Напишу пример и скину на гитхаб

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Сделал "мини-видео". Чтобы наглядно показать https://youtu.be/Qe769KCoqsg

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://github.com/karpov-dev/lab4-GUI- - сам проект